# Is it possible to programmatically freeze threads on Windows?

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio, thread-safety

In visual studio, for example, one can freeze/thaw any thread at any time. Is is possible to do this programmatically in order to create a stress test of sorts for threaded code?  If any thread could be frozen randomly for a random amount of time, it would really exercise the synchronization logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with SuspendThread & ResumeThread, you'll need the thread handle which you get by calling OpenThread.  The [thread functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684847%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#thread_functions) page on msdn is a good resource for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 1):

you can create a `Thread` which randomly picks `Thread's` from `ThreadPool` and put them to sleep for random amount of time. If that's what you are after.

Comment: even just suspending them and 'immediately' resuming them would probably provide suitably non-deterministic delays.

Comment: Not all threads are part of a thread pool.  And you're not introducing delays into tasks (to test for race conditions), you're just using up the thread pool.  -1

Comment: @BenVoigt I understand, but i was only providing concept, I am not sure what the actual code looks like and how the threads are being instantiated in gultz code.